# Python 3 Number name length

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a little program that displays the length of a number's (x) name. I got this bit of code, but writing out every darn number name in the list (Numn) just seems too cluttered and tedious. Any tips on how to do it faster and more efficiently?

```
def NN(x):
    a = x - 1
    Numn = ["one", "eleven", "twentyone"]
    print(len(Numn[a]))

NN(1)
```

Comment: Spelling out numbers with words is not an easy task. That alone is it's own small project. You might want to try something easier to start out with, or be prepared to work on this for awhile. This is far too broad for here though.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-number-to-words/

Comment: That is for C# :P

Comment: @RinusSteynberg There's a Python implementation at the bottom.